# Get Columns of another table located in another database on the current server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

My current selected database is `DATABASE_A`. I would like to write a `SELECT` query that returns all the column names of `TABLE_NAME` that are located on another database called `DATABASE_B`. Both databases are located on the same server. Is that possible?

**Update:** I think I would have improve my question: What I have in hand is not two separate variables for the name of the database and the name of the table. That means all I have is `DATABASE_B`.`TABLE_NAME`. In the the current answers (which are actually very correct), we are able to separate database name from table name.

Comment: With proper permissions set up, yes, you can reference another database on the same server.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my updated procedure:

```
declare @dbName varchar(100),
        @tableName varchar(100)

declare @stringToParse varchar(1000) = 'DatabaseName.TableName'

set     @dbName = SUBSTRING(@stringToParse, 0, charindex('.', @stringToParse))
set     @tableName = SUBSTRING(@stringToParse, charindex('.', @stringToParse) + 1, len(@stringToParse) - charindex('.', @stringToParse))

select  @dbName, @tableName



declare @stringToExecute varchar(max) = 'select  c.name
from    ' + @dbName + '.sys.tables t inner join
        ' + @dbName + '.sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
where   t.name = ''' +  @tableName + ''''

select  @stringToExecute -- this will show you what was generated
exec(@stringToExecute) -- this will run the sql that was generated.
```

Here is the output from `select @stringToExecute`

```
select  c.name
from    DatabaseName.sys.tables t inner join
        databaseName.sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
where   t.name = 'TableName'
```

I'm not sure where the database and table names come from, but generating this dynamic SQL is **extremely** dangerous! While this code will get you what you want, you may want to re-think it before putting it to use.

Comment: please see the update. I'm sorry if I could not explain myself correctly.

Comment: I want to clarify your update - do you have the name of that database that the table exists in and do you also have the table name that includes the columns you want listed?

Comment: yes. in the form of `dbname.tablename`, but not separately.

Comment: See my update for what you can use.  Be aware of dynamically generated SQL as it opens you up to SQL Injection.

Comment: Your answer is terrific and I accepted that. But I still cannot trust the part that says `@dbName = SUBSTRING(@stringToParse, 0, charindex('.', @stringToParse))`. In some cases the database name may be `Something.Something`.

Comment: I gotcha. That piece should be pretty straight-forward as that is only the piece that parses the names.  Without having the context of how this is used it will be difficult to handle all situations.  Feel free to show some examples and I'll see if I can come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

use `Information_Schema.Columns` with `Database` name

```
USE DATABASE_A

SELECT *
FROM   DATABASE_B.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

Comment: please see the update. I'm sorry if I could not explain myself correctly.